# Keep class from shrinking

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, shrink

In my android app I have a `DbHelper` class which extends `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Running **ProGuard** on project completes successfully, but later in run-time I'm getting an error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.myapp.mypackage.DbHelper`

I'm added `-keep class com.example.myapp.mypackage.** { *; }` into `proguard-project.txt` to exclude my `DbHelper` from shrinking but this doesn't helps.

Also I've tried to add `-dontshrink` flag, just for test, to disable shrinking step, but this doesn't helps too.

Any suggestions what I do wrong and what to try? Thanks

**UPD:** Full stacktrace

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.myapp.mypackage.DbHelper
    at com.example.myapp.App.onCreate(App.java:78)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPD 2:**
For OrmLite I'm using this config

```
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

**UPD 3:**
I'm tryed to undex `classes.dex` from proguarded apk with `dex2jar` tool and my DbHelper exists exactly where it should be

**UPD 4:**
Nope, this isn't test application, this is usual android app

**UPD 5:**
Yes, `DbHelper` use some kind of stuff from support package and in proguarded apk classes from suppord package is missed. In `proguard-project.txt` I have this config for support package and Action Bar Sherlock

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
```

How I can correctly configure ProGuard to preserve support package from shrinking?

Comment: `com.example.myapp.mypackage.DbHelper` should be in the final APK. Can you post more from stacktrace? To be sure DBHelper is there, you can unpack the APK and undex the classes.dex file

Comment: Have you tried to `keep` your `DbHelper` and `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` simultaneously?

Comment: strange ... can you unpack the final APK, undex it and compare the source structure with your expectation?

Comment: Is this a Android test application?

Comment: Does DBHelper extend or use something from support package? Are the classes from support package exported in the final APK? I was getting these kind of issues when I was not exporting Android private libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @gunar for help. I solved the problem, the reason is that I include support package in `proguard-project.txt` as `-libraryjars` not as `-injars`. Therefore it's content wasn't packed into resulting apk and dalvik cannot initialize DbHelper at runtime which uses classes from support package